# In Active Directory, what is a resource?

Tags: adal

In the examples and tests for the AAD node.js library, `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is always passed as the resource. What is `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`?

The [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/731946bcfa8cb7ed709a099df791ed0906f06452/lib/authentication-context.js#L245) just says that a resource is "A URI that identifies the resource for which the token is valid." But `00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is a UUID. What is a resource, and what can the value here be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to answer one part of your question, 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 is the app id of the Graph API in all tenants. If you do not pass in a resource parameter when requesting an OAuth 2.0 token it defaults to this.
Source: [Azure Active Directory application model](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2473127)

Comment: Yeah, i had figured that out a while ago, but forgot that i even had this question open. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is a resourceAppId. Add: If you already have a web app, Click "Download Manifest", you could find the resourceAppId in the JSON Manifest file.
[image]

[image]

You could find these apps in `Permissions to other applications` as below picture, config your web app permission to other application, if the resource application is selected, it will display in Manifest.
[image]

If you want to know more information, pls refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-application-manifest/

Comment: I've seen it in referenced in a lot of Active Directory libraries, could it be the equivalent in AD of "localhost and 120.0.0.1" in networking? (As in a known resource that will return something?)

Comment: I add the details. It is resource application id, config your web app permission through selecting these resource apps.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the other half of my question, a resource is any kind of entity that can be accessed by an application. In Azure, they are referenced via their [URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/URI). Examples include:

- `https://graph.microsoft.com`
- `http://localhost:8080`
- `https://mydevapp.azurewebsites.net`
- `spn:d13730c8-d56f-4d9e-9e1a-9e2afebbca46`

`00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is merely a short form of the URI `spn:00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000`, which, as mentioned, is the app id of the Graph API in all tenants