# ADAL.NET v3 does not support AcquireToken with UserCredential?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, adal

In ADAL.NET 2.x, we use the below code to acquire token from Azure AD using `UserCredential` and it works perfectly:

```
 var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
 var userCredential = new UserCredential(username, password);
 var token = authContext.AcquireToken(ResourceUrl, ClientId, userCredential);
```

When I upgraded ADAL.NET v3 today, the code cannot be compiled anymore because on the new version, `UserCredential` does not have overloaded constructor with username and password.

How I can workaround this with the new version of ADAL.NET v3?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `UserPasswordCredential` class instead which is a subclass of UserCredential

Comment: I get AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.
Trace ID: 8be09594-65c2-4e2d-bce2-17980f739371
Correlation ID: 7312b657-f6d4-4d0b-8fc2-c66f1b9f0325
Timestamp: 2016-12-28 16:14:16Z

Comment: you are trying to use confidential client (web api) id for a native application. You need to create a new native app id for your flow

Comment: Hey im using this and in debug configuration it works fine but in release i get AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password even though im using the same password username, any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 3):

Try `UserPasswordCredential`, the class had to be renamed in v3.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, it seems as though they have removed this functionality from ADAL. [source](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/482)

To authenticate with a users username/password combo, I believe you will have to use HttpClient and make the post request yourself.

Post to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
```

with:

```
resource={resource}&client_id={clientid}&grant_type=password&username={username}&password={password}&scope=openid&client_secret={clientsecret}
```

in the request

Comment: What is the value for "resource" parameter in the request body? I am guessing but it does not work.

Comment: Hi @SameekshaKumari, this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297546/in-active-directory-what-is-a-resource?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2):

This fixes the issue for the UserCredentials, but you also seems to be a change to the AuthenticationContext type which no longer seems to have an AcquireToken method. You can address this by using AcquireTokenAsync