# Generate bearer token client side C#

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, azure-active-directory

Im am working with a REST service deployed in an azure environment. I want to run some integration testing by calling various API functions from a separate (console) application. But the REST api uses bearer token authentication. Im a total noob with azure authentications, so i don't even know if it should be possible.

I've tried to use the example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407952/adal-net-core-nuget-package-does-not-support-userpasswordcredential) but no luck yet.

In anycase, I have two applications. One is the console app that is running the code, and the other is the Rest service for which i need to use the bearer token to access the API calls. I will call them the ConsoleApp and RestService.

The code I run is as following:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string tenantId = "<Azure tenant id>";
string tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token";
string resourceUrl = "<RestService app id url>";
string clientId = "<azure id of the ConsoleApp>";
string userName = "derp@flerp.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "somepassword";

string tokenEndpoint = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/token";
var body = $"resource={resourceUrl}&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}";
var stringContent = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var result=await client.PostAsync(tokenEndpoint, stringContent).ContinueWith<string>((response) =>
{
    return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
});
```

JObject jobject = JObject.Parse(result);

The Json message I get back:

> error: invalid_grant, error_description: AADSTS50105: The signed in
> user is not assigned to a role for the application "RestService
> azureid"

What does that mean, and how what needs to be done to get a bearer token out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please firstly check whether you enabled the `User assignment required` of console application :

In your azure ad blade ,click `Enterprise applications` ,search your app in `All applications` blade ,click `Properties` :
[image]

If enabled that , and your account not assigned access role in your app , then you will get the error . Please try to assign access role in your app :

In your azure ad blade ,click `Enterprise applications` ,search your console app in `All applications` blade ,click `Users and groups` , click `Add User` button , select your account and assign role(edit user and ensure `select role` is not `None Selected`):

[image]

Please let me know whether it helps.

Comment: The console app has the user assignment switched off, the service has it switched on. I'm gonna see if i can do something with this information

Comment: So I added the permission to the service and that managed to solve my issue. Thanks a lot!