# Passing user credentials to Adal AquireTokenAsync

Tags: mobile, active-directory, passwords, credentials, adal

I am using Adal (Active Directory Authentication Library) Version 3.13.x. I am doing something like below to fetch the Access token

```
AuthResult = await AuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(relyingUrl, ServiceConstants.CLIENTID, ServiceConstants.RETURNURI, param);
```

I need to pass the UserCredentials along as well, but right now I can only pass one parameter to the UserCredential() unlike in the Versions 2.x.x of Adal.

I also tried using `UserPasswordCredential` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465949/adal-net-v3-does-not-support-acquiretoken-with-usercredential) solution , but since I want to Fetch the token from a  Mobile app, I only have access to .net Core and hence can not use `UserPasswordCredential`

I want to pass the username and password together while acquiring the token. Is there any way i can achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

### EDIT

After trying out the solution from Fei Xue - MSFT, i get the following 503 error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass the username and password together while acquiring the token. Is there any way i can achieve this?

In this scenario, we can perform the REST request directly instead of using the client library. Here is a sample for your reference:

```
Post:https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token

resource={resource}&client_id={clientId}&grant_type=password&username={userName}&password={password}
```

### Update

```
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}";
string resrouce = "https://graph.windows.net";

string clientId = "";
string userName = "";
string password = "";
UserPasswordCredential userPasswordCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var token = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resrouce, clientId, userPasswordCredential).Result.AccessToken;

Console.WriteLine(token);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. any idea how I can do this with the authority being AD FS?

Comment: Not familiar with AD FS, however you can try to use the library to acquire the token using this flow and capture the request via Fiddler for the detail.

Comment: Please check my Edit. I am quite new to this hence the issues.

Comment: Was the request successful if you send using the Adal library?

Comment: I haven't tried using this approach with adal. Can you please show me how?

Comment: @PoojaGaonkar I have updated the post to append a code sample to use **Resource Owner Password Credentials** flow. However this C# code sample is for acquiring the token from the Azure AD. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But as I mentioned in the Question since I am doing this on a mobile app, I only have access to .net Core. Hence I cannot access UserPasswordCredential

Comment: The code sample is used to help us to capture the request which parameters we need to perform. So that we can compose the request ourselves as the original post I suggested.