# ADFS single sign on for logged on user not working

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, adal

I am trying to integrate our application a regular .net desktop service that runs in the user context with ADFS, and a Web API. The user is a domain user and this is a regular AD environment. The MVC aspect of the website are working well with the browser.

I am on ADAL3(VS2017), windows server 2016, I referred this link [[ADFS SSO CloudIdentity]](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/) am able to use `UserCredentialPassword` to get a token successfully and call into my Web API, I just followed the steps and changed things to async.

However using the logged on credential bit where a `new UserCredential()` should indicate to call to get the token from current thread doesn't work at all for me, on ADAL 2, I am getting null pointer exception and on ADAL3 I get

*MSIS7065: There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/oauth2/token to process the incoming request.*

I did see a similar query on SO but based on my understanding the OP there is falling back on browser based behaviour.

Falling back at browser based auth (with Promptbehaviour.never) based behaviour is undesired because I have seen a lot of config issues on customer site where even with the relevant settings enabled the browser was assuming it to be an internet site and logging in fails.

Code for reference

```
string authority = "https://adfs.domain.com/adfs";
string resourceURI = "https://local.ip:44325";
string clientID = "19cda707-b1bf-48a1-b4ac-a7df00e1a689";
AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
// I expect that the user's credential are picked up here.
AuthenticationResult authResult = 
    await ac.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceURI, clientID, 
                               new UserCredential());
string authHeader = authResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Get,
                      "https://local.ip:44325/api/values");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation( "Authorization", authHeader);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The call fails in acquiretokenasync.

Answer (score 0):

Have you violated any of the constraints described [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/)?

Also, similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465949/adal-net-v3-does-not-support-acquiretoken-with-usercredential) around ADAL V3.0 and UserCredential support.

In the link above, the RP was created using PowerShell. Are you sure that you have properly configured an application in ADFS 4.0 - clientID etc.

Comment: @nzpcmd thanks, it is a regular AD adfs scenario, AAD is not in picture as I said in the post I can authenticate with a userPasswordCredential correctly for the same user. Problem happens with the userCredential.

Comment: Since I can't edit the previous content here is more to it, it appears the adal is automatically picking up Forms Authentication and not really using windows authentication. In ADFS when I disabled Forms authentication (windows auth was the only way left) UserPasswordCredential stopped working as well.